# Image now showing up but the path is right (Flask)

Tags: html, flask

I've just started to build this website. The code and file directory structure couldn't be simpler. The image sources (kakao_account_...) are in the same directory (templates) with the template file (index.html).

[image]

#### index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    </head>
<body>
    <img src="kakao_account_login_btn_medium_narrow.png">
</body>
</html>
```

The file sizes ranges between 3KB~4KB and I've both tried jpeg and png. I get 404 http response for the image element.
The back side is run with Flask and I'm using my computer as the server. I'm trying to check file permission status as [this article](https://blog.teamtreehouse.com/how-to-fix-a-broken-image) suggests using Cyberduck but it keeps giving me an error and I don't even know if this works for a local server. At least the image file is set as readable for everyone in my computer if that helps.

Comment: Try using ```src="./kakao_account_login_btn_medium_narrow.png"```

Comment: @S.Ramjit Thank you but it doesn't work either..

Comment: Add the alt attribute? alt="button image" as well as the CSS that others have mentioned.

Comment: @S.Ramjit I found the problem was in the back side... but thank you for trying to solve the problem!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This turned out to be a problem coming from the back side.
I opened the index.html directly without flask and the image is shown correctly. It looks like I had to make a folder named `static` and put the image there.

[image]

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    </head>
<body>
    <img src="../static/kakao_account_login_btn_medium_narrow.png">
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding some height to your image.

Try something like this:

```css
img {
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
</head>

<body>
  <img src="https://www.incimages.com/uploaded_files/image/970x450/getty_152414899_97046097045006_68075.jpg">
</body>

</html>
```

Hope it works!

Comment: That one worked fine... But I wish I can include image from my local storage!